# Writing integration tests for a Flex app using SqLite

Tags: apache-flex

I want to write integration tests for a Flex application using pureMVC architecture.The back-end is sqlite.Anyone has experience doing this? Any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: Can you quantify what an integration test?  What exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: Say for a scenario - add customer.I want to test that when Add Customer is called,data goes into the database.For this,test I might have to fill the database with some data.In dotnet,we use NDBUnit with xml files to load test data into the database.

Answer (score -1):

Well i have been using Cairngorm Framework as my MVC, at first looking at the structure makes me puke. but in the later part of coding, i realize that these MVC is really handy and well organize. hope it helps.. heres a link to its wiki

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cairngorm_(Flex_framework)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cairngorm_%28Flex_framework%29)

Comment: What does Cairngorm have to do with integration tests?